# how i can remove hook in prestashop?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

```
    public function install()
{
    if (parent::install()===false) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($this->registerHook('actionValidateOrder') == false) {
        return false;
    }
    if ($this->registerHook('actionObjectOrderSlipAddAfter') == false) {
        return false;
    }
    $this->saveDefaultConfig();
    // replace some a part of tpl file
    require_once(_PS_MODULE_DIR_ . "ba_prestashop_invoice/includes/helper.php");
    BAInvoiceHelper::configOldTplFile();
    return true;
}
```

during the installation of a module it inserts these elements in the hook, I do not know how I can delete it?
because i get this error livraison
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method OrderInvoice::getDeliveryNumberFormatted() ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this:
    $this->unregisterHook('HookName');
But I think that your error is not related to hooks

Answer (score 0):

simply go to admin/themes/default/template/controllers/orders/_documents.tpl 
on line 79 delete or comment these lines of code 
and it will fix your issue

```
{if get_class($document) eq 'OrderInvoice'}
    {if isset($document->is_delivery)}
        {$document->getDeliveryNumberFormatted($current_id_lang, $order->id_shop)}
    {else}
        {$document->getInvoiceNumberFormatted($current_id_lang, $order->id_shop)}
    {/if}
{elseif get_class($document) eq 'OrderSlip'}
    {$document->getCreditSlipsNumberFormatted($current_id_lang, $order->id_shop)}
{/if}
```